# Events in my UserControl won't fire up - why?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I placed a custom UserControl in my window and set the MouseDoubleClick event inside my usesr-control to change some of its properties.

However, using breakpoints, I realized that the MouseDoubleClick event is never fired. That's true for any event I set in my user-control.

What am I missing ?

btw: I also created some DependencyProperty, "by the book", which works well, if it helps...

Comment: If you did it right it should probably work.  But we can't possibly know if you did if you don't show us the code you actually have.  _Please_ post your code.

Comment: code or it didn't happen

Comment: maybe you didn't double-click your control? ;)

Comment: You're all right... my bad... while editing the xaml code for easy reading to paste in here, I noticed there is no `"MouseDoubleClick="` in the `ListView` tag... although the Blend-Xpression **did** show the `MouseDoubleClick` in the events list...

... _should_ look more often in the xaml itself...

@JohnKZ , @Rick , @Jeff , @flq , @surfen : Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to handle `MouseDoubleClick` in your `UserControl`.

Create a new user control called `UserControl1`.  Here is the body of `UserControl.xaml`:

```
<Grid Background="Red">
    <!-- leave this blank at first -->
</Grid>
```

We've set the background to red so we can see that we're working with the user control.  Also, it needs a background in order to to receive the click events.

Add a double-click method override in the code-behind for the user control in `UserControl1.xaml.cs`:

```
protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e);
    MessageBox.Show("Double-Click!");
}
```

Now create a window and add your user control to it, e.g. `Window1.xaml`:

```
<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1/>
</Grid>
```

Run your program so that `Window1` is display and the whole window should be red.  Double-click on the window and you'll see a message-box:

[image]

Once all this is working you can continue with whatever other goal you needed to use the double-click event for.

Answer (score 0):

Set up background for you `User Control`. It may be `Transparent` or `White`.